# How to do a proper double or triple bash quote escape?

Tags: bash, escaping, quotes, double-quotes

```
#!/bin/bash
# this works: java '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=nohup bash -c "service jira stop;service jira stop" &' -version
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="" # WHAT TO PUT HERE !?! so the last line will execute the command above?
JAVA_OPTS=" ${JAVA_OPTS} ${JVM_REQUIRED_ARGS} ${DISABLE_NOTIFICATIONS} ${JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS} ${JVM_EXTRA_ARGS} ${JIRA_HOME_MINUSD}"
set -x
java $JAVA_OPTS -version
```

If possible don't touch other lines than the JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although @raukh's answer is right, i.e. you have to escape the `"`, you are also missing another point.

Answer for the impatient: you need to add `\"` around `${JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS}` also, to prevent bash from separating the contents of `JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS` to different argument.

---

Complete answer:

Imagine this example, assuming `print_args` is a program that echoes its arguments each in one line

```
TEST="a b"
./print_args $TEST
```

This will output `a` and `b` as separate arguments. This is because the `"` is removed and in fact the executed command is:

```
./print_args a b
```

To make your command see your variable all as one parameter, you have to put it in `"`:

```
TEST="a b"
./print_args "$TEST"
```

Will show `a b` as one argument.

Even if you write extra `"` in your string, it won't work, as bash will separate the contents of the variable anyway:

```
TEST="\"a b\""
./print_args $TEST
```

will give you `"a` and `b"` as separate arguments. The only way you can handle this, is to add `"` where you *use* the variable, instead of where you define it.

So in your case, the solution is this:

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="java '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=nohup bash -c \"service jira stop;service jira stop\" &' test"
JAVA_OPTS=" ${JAVA_OPTS} ${JVM_REQUIRED_ARGS} ${DISABLE_NOTIFICATIONS} \"${JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS}\" ${JVM_EXTRA_ARGS} ${JIRA_HOME_MINUSD}"
```

The first line is as raukh suggested. The second line has added `\"` around `${JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS}`.

---

If you want to test this, here is an example:

```
test.c:

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -o print_args test.c

$ TEST="java '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=nohup bash -c \"service jira stop;service jira stop\" &' test"; ./print_args $TEST
0: ./print_args
1: java
2: '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=nohup
3: bash
4: -c
5: "service
6: jira
7: stop;service
8: jira
9: stop"
10: &'
11: test

$ TEST="java '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=nohup bash -c \"service jira stop;service jira stop\" &' test"; ./print_args "$TEST"
0: ./print_args
1: java '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=nohup bash -c "service jira stop;service jira stop" &' test
```

Comment: Wow, that was a long answer. I rewrited the question to make it easier. I am looking for a one line solution, nothing more, or less. Something that will not require modifications outside this single line.

Comment: @votingmeisfree, I'm afraid you can't. All you need to do is to include `\"` around `${JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS}`. Is that not possible?!

Comment: The reason is that, bash _will_ expand your variable into different arguments (even if there is `"` in the variable itself, see the example above in arguments 5 to 9.). The only way (that I know of) to avoid this is to put `$VARIABLE` inside `"` on usage.

Comment: Thanks, i would only recommend to try to remove the boilerplate from the solution. Most people do like short answers ;)

Comment: @votingmeisfree, thanks for the suggestion. I'll reorganize the answer.